# Add values from columns in two files when rows not matching

Tags: shell, awk, paste

I have two files that have some common columns and few are not and I am trying to add columns associated with common columns as follows:

```
 paste file1 file2
M246_0.6.motif_CBS_count    15023   M246_0.6.motif_CBS_count    15767
M247_0.6.motif_CBS_count    15023   M247_0.6.motif_CBS_count    15767
M250_0.6.motif_CBS_count    8483    M250_0.6.motif_CBS_count    8815
M254_0.6.motif_CBS_count    12921   M254_0.6.motif_CBS_count    13435
M256_0.6.motif_CBS_count    36045   M256_0.6.motif_CBS_count    39390
M261_0.6.motif_CBS_count    6339    M260_0.6.motif_CBS_count    2
M262_0.6.motif_CBS_count    1026    M261_0.6.motif_CBS_count    6523
M269_0.6.motif_CBS_count    47      M262_0.6.motif_CBS_count    863
M271_0.6.motif_CBS_count    7162    M269_0.6.motif_CBS_count    57
M272_0.6.motif_CBS_count    2245    M271_0.6.motif_CBS_count    8218
M273_0.6.motif_CBS_count    159     M272_0.6.motif_CBS_count    2459
```

Note here that file2 contains M260 that file1 doesn't , all I want to do is a) add up column2 from both files that have common column1 and leave the uncommon ones as they are such that

```
 M246_0.6.motif_CBS_count   30790
 M247_0.6.motif_CBS_count   30790
 M250_0.6.motif_CBS_count   17298
 M254_0.6.motif_CBS_count   26356
 M256_0.6.motif_CBS_count   75435
 M260_0.6.motif_CBS_count   2
 M261_0.6.motif_CBS_count   72862   
 M262_0.6.motif_CBS_count   1889    
 M269_0.6.motif_CBS_count   104    
 M271_0.6.motif_CBS_count   15380
 M272_0.6.motif_CBS_count   10463 
 M272_0.6.motif_CBS_count   2459
 M273_0.6.motif_CBS_count   159
```

Comment: `M260_0.6.motif_CBS_count` is `12862` and `M272_0.6.motif_CBS_count` is `4704`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with `gawk`, feature `PROCINFO` that is specific to gawk (If output order doesn't matter then remove this line)

```
awk '{d[$1]+=$2}
     END{
         PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"; 
         for(k in d){ print k, d[k] }
     }' file1 file2
```

you get,

```
M246_0.6.motif_CBS_count 30790
M247_0.6.motif_CBS_count 30790
M250_0.6.motif_CBS_count 17298
M254_0.6.motif_CBS_count 26356
M256_0.6.motif_CBS_count 75435
M260_0.6.motif_CBS_count 2
M261_0.6.motif_CBS_count 12862
M262_0.6.motif_CBS_count 1889
M269_0.6.motif_CBS_count 104
M271_0.6.motif_CBS_count 15380
M272_0.6.motif_CBS_count 4704
M273_0.6.motif_CBS_count 159
```